# Entity-framework generated query throws ORA-12704 when using TO_CHAR or TO_NUMBER

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I currently face the problem, that I get an exception when executing a query generated by the entity framework.

The query worked until I've joined another table using `.include()` to the existing entity. Now, whenever I execute the query, I get an Oracle error `ORA-12704 character set mismatch`.

I narrowed the problem down to the following:

Before joining the table, the generated SQL is a simple query with some `join` statements. After joining another table, the generated SQL cointains two subqueries which are combined using `UNION ALL`. In one of the subqueries, a lot of helper-columns are selected.

They look like this:

```
SELECT 
    ... some other columns...
    TO_NUMBER(NULL) AS C1,
    TO_CHAR(NULL) AS C2,
    ...
```

If I remove those columns and also the corresponding ones in the other subquery, no error is thrown. When I replace the columns with `NULL` instead of `TO_XXX(NULL)`, the query also works as expected.

Is there any way force the entity-framework not to use these problematic casts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused with the usage of a `NVARCHAR2` column in combination with the function `TO_CHAR` (that returns `VARCHAR2` data type)  as illustrated below

```
create table tab
(txt nvarchar2(10));

select txt from tab
union all
select to_char(null) from dual;
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

So your goal is to motivate the tool to generate a query that uses either `TO_NCHAR(null)` or `cast(null as nvarchar2(10))` - both will work.

To do this, you need to add the following data-annotation to the property of the corresponding entity:

```
[Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR2")]
```

The given TypeName must match with the type of the column in the database.
After this addition, the entityframework will generate the correct casts. In this case, the following cast ist generated:

```
SELECT
   ...
   TO_NCHAR(NULL),
   ...
```

You should see no problem with the `to_number(null)` if the corresponding `UNION`column is of a *number*  datatype.

Comment: This should be more a *comment* as it does not provide a solution, but is to large for it, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve my problem. I'll update your answer with my solution.